# Selecting #2 element inside every div X

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a script which will change the content of every occurence like this:

```
<div id="random numbers">
<div class="column-1"></div>
<div class="column-1"><a href="...">this value I want to change</a></div>
<div class="column-1"></div>
</div>
```

there's many of those^
so far, this is the code I'm trying to make use of:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('column-1');

for ( var i=elements.length; i--; ) {
    elements[ i ].InnerHTML = "test";
}
```

but this isn't working, and I'm really just trying to piece together some code that will replace the content of the #2 column-1 of every `<div id="random numbers">`

I appreciate any help here, thanks in advance

Comment: Your query should be `.column-1` (with period to target classes), and the property you're likely trying to set is `innerHTML` with a lowercase `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your above code. First, your [**`.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) should be targeting the **class**; you need to specify the full stop. Second, the `i` in [**`.innerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) needs to be lowercase.

After these two bugs have been fixed, you can only apply the change to every **second** element by running a condition based on a **[modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)** of 2 using `i % 2` as follows:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-1');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="random numbers">
  <div class="column-1">Should STAY</div>
  <div class="column-1"><a href="...">Should CHANGE</a></div>
  <div class="column-1">Should STAY</div>
</div>
```

If you're specifically trying to target the `<a>` tags, you can do that directly with `querySelectorAll('.column-1 a')` itself, using [**`.outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) if you want to replace the `<a>` tag itself. Note that this doesn't require a conditional:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.column-1 a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].outerHTML = "OVERRIDDEN";
}
```

```html
<div id="random numbers">
  <div class="column-1">Should STAY</div>
  <div class="column-1"><a href="...">Should CHANGE</a></div>
  <div class="column-1">Should STAY</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'd lean towards i === 2 instead of the modulus operator on the off chance some of them have 4 or more columns.

Comment: ^ That is certainly a possible alternative. Note that `i % 2` will hit **every** second iteration (2, 4, 6, etc.), whereas `i === 2` will **only** hit the second one (and not the 4th or 6th). Feel free to swap that if need be :)

Comment: hi, thanks! this is seemingly working somewhat for my purposes, except there's many of these divs and as you say here its changing 1, 3, 5, etc and I would need it to change #2 in each one, is that possible?

Comment: sorry there's actually an <a> inside each of the divs, not just the middle one

Comment: If you want it to target every **other** element, you can simply negate the conditional. `if (i % 2)` will target 2, 4, 6, etc. and `if (i % 2 === 0)` will target 1, 3, 5, etc.